# no password ssh auth in new amazon instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, rsync

I have a script that interact with an external host with rsync/ssh.

SSH prompts me to confirm the authenticity of the host like this:

```
The authenticity of host 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Since every EC2 instance is a new host, I have to confirm this every time, but I want an automatic script without any user input. What is the best solution?

I know I can add -O StrictHostKeyChecking=no , but that would make external host insecure.

EDIT ! : is it possible to use my PEM file to authenticate in other servers ? I mean, mayb installing something in the external server and connect in the same way I do with instances and the PEM file

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this article [verify-ssh-keys-on-ec2-instances](http://ubuntu-smoser.blogspot.com/2010/07/verify-ssh-keys-on-ec2-instances.html) might have the information you need, or at least a starting point to scripting something.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect):

> Expect is a Unix automation and
>   testing tool, written by Don Libes as
>   an extension to the Tcl scripting
>   language, for interactive applications
>   such as telnet, ftp, passwd, fsck,
>   rlogin, tip, ssh, and others. It uses
>   Unix pseudo terminals to wrap up
>   subprocesses transparently, allowing
>   the automation of arbitrary
>   applications that are accessed over a
>   terminal.

Although you might have some challenge to make it work in those cases where you connect to the same IP for a non-first time and ssh will not ask.